# Property or indexer 'System.DateTime.TimeOfDay' cannot be assigned to — it is read only

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetimepicker

I saw lots of duplicate post of this But for me it's something different.

I have a Datetime object and get time portion & assign another time to that.When i'm going to assign it it raise those error.

in here newStartDateGroup is a DateTime Object
in here OpenTime is a TimeSpan

> > Property or indexer cannot be assigned to — it is read only

```
else if(newStartDateGroup.TimeOfDay < i.OpenTime && newEndDateGroup.TimeOfDay > i.CloseTime) // < >
 {
        newStartDateGroup.TimeOfDay = i.OpenTime;
```

Answer (score 7):

[`DateTime` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) in .NET is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so instead of changing it's values you have to create new one:

```
newStartDateGroup = newStartDateGroup.Date.Add(i.OpenTime);
```

Comment: There's an alternative syntax for the same, namely `newStartDateGroup = newStartDateGroup.Date + i.OpenTime;`, that I would prefer, but that's only a matter of taste/style.

Answer (score 3):

You can only create new [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx#instantiating_datetime) instances.

According to your shown code, you want to set only the day time.
This should do it:

```
newStartDateGroup = DateTime.Today.Add(i.OpenTime);
```

`DateTime.Today` is today at 00:00.

Comment: The `.Today.` part does not make sense (you cannot access a static member through a concrete instance) and is not needed when you have `.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the hours, minutes and seconds manually.

```
DateTime temp = DateTime(newStartDateGroup.Year, newStartDateGroup.Month, newStartDateGroup.Day, i.OpenTime.Hours, i.OpenTime.Minutes, i.OpenTime.Seconds);

newStartDateGroup = temp;
```